# TransformerFactoryImpl class loading issue

Tags: xslt, osgi, saxon, osgi-bundle

We are trying to validate the resource using Saxon jar,  which uses XSLT 2 `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`, but `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` is getting used every time.

This is something related to loading of classes. We have added the Saxon jar in classpath, but still getting same error.

Can someone please help me on this.

JUST FYI - we are using osgi bundle. Same works fine if its standalone java class.

Thanks,
Hrushi

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687871/unable-to-force-eclipse-to-use-saxon-xslt-processor/51792040#51792040. You need to add the saxon jar to your bundle, add it to the bundle class path and explicity load the Saxon transformer factory.